# PHP include within jQuery next() conflict

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

If you'll take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Qw75j/7/ you'll see what I'm looking for.

I want to be able to include PHP within each of the DIVs though. The PHP appears to load just fine if I include it in the first DIV, but if I place the PHP in the second DIV as well, or just in the second or third DIV, the next() functionality breaks. The goal is to display a different calendar month once the user clicks "Next" or "Previous".

I have four resources that are working together. The HTML/PHP for the index, the jQuery for the next() functionality, and the PHP & CSS for some calendar code.

How do I embed separate PHP pages within each next()-related DIV?

Thanks beforehand for any help. I'm truly stumped.

**index.php:**

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style2.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>

  <button id="prev" disabled="disabled">Prev</button>
  <button id="next">Next</button>

    <div id="cal1" class="first current">
        <?php echo '<span class="monthName">'.$nmonth.' '.$cyear.'</span>';
              echo draw_calendar($cmonth,$cyear); ?>
        <span class="prevMonth"></span>
    </div>

    <div id="cal2">
        <?php echo '<span class="monthName">'.$nmonth.' '.$cyear.'</span>';
              echo draw_calendar($cmonth,$cyear); ?>
        <span class="prevMonth"></span>
    </div>

    <div id="cal3" class="last">
        <?php
        echo '<span class="monthName">'.$nmonth.' '.$cyear.'</span>';
        echo draw_calendar($cmonth,$cyear); ?>
        <span class="prevMonth"></span>
    </div>

</body>
<script>
  $('#next').click(function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
        .next().show().addClass('current');
    if ($('.current').hasClass('last')) {
        $('#next').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    $('#prev').attr('disabled', null);
});

$('#prev').click(function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
        .prev().show().addClass('current');
    if ($('.current').hasClass('first')) {
        $('#prev').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    $('#next').attr('disabled', null);
});
</script>
</html>
```

**calendar.php:**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calendar.css" />
</head>
</html>
<?php
/* draws a calendar */
function draw_calendar($month,$year){

    /* draw table */
    $calendar = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">';

    /* table headings */
    $headings = array('SUN','MON','TUES','WED','THURS','FRI','SAT');
    $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row"><td class="calendar-day-head">'.implode('</td><td class="calendar-day-head">',$headings).'</td></tr>';

    /* days and weeks vars now ... */
    $running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $days_in_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $days_in_this_week = 1;
    $day_counter = 0;
    $dates_array = array();

    /* row for week one */
    $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';

    /* print "blank" days until the first of the current week */
    for($x = 0; $x < $running_day; $x++):
        $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>';
        $days_in_this_week++;
    endfor;

    /* keep going with days.... */
    for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):
        $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day">';
            /* add in the day number */
            $calendar.= '<div class="day-number"><a href="">'.$list_day.'</a><input type="hidden" name="day" value="'.$list_day.'"></div>';

            /** QUERY THE DATABASE FOR AN ENTRY FOR THIS DAY !!  IF MATCHES FOUND, PRINT THEM !! **/
            $calendar.= str_repeat('&nbsp',2);

        $calendar.= '</td>';
        if($running_day == 6):
            $calendar.= '</tr>';
            if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
                $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
            endif;
            $running_day = -1;
            $days_in_this_week = 0;
        endif;
        $days_in_this_week++; $running_day++; $day_counter++;
    endfor;

    /* finish the rest of the days in the week */
    if($days_in_this_week < 8):
        for($x = 1; $x <= (8 - $days_in_this_week); $x++):
            $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>';
        endfor;
    endif;

    /* final row */
    $calendar.= '</tr>';

    /* end the table */
    $calendar.= '</table>';

    /* all done, return result */
    return $calendar;
}
        $cmonth = date('m');
        $nmonth = date('F');
        $cyear = date('Y');
?>
```

**calendar.css:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family:Gotham-Medium;
    src: url(./css/GothamMedium.ttf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family:Gotham-Light;
    src: url(./css/Gotham-Light.ttf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family:Gotham-Bold;
    src: url(./css/Gotham-Bold.otf);
}
/* calendar */
td.calendar-day { 
    min-height:30px; 
    font-size:11px; 
    position:relative;
    background:#000;
} 
* html div.calendar-day { 
    height:30px;
    font-family:Gotham-Medium;
}
td.calendar-day-np  { 
    background:#000; 
    min-height:30px; 
} 
* html div.calendar-day-np { 
    height:30px; 
}
td.calendar-day-head { 
    background:#000;
    color:#BBA324;
    font-family:Gotham-Medium;
    font-size:12px; 
    text-align:center; 
    width:60px; 
    padding:5px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    border:0;
}
div.day-number { 
    background:transparent;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:Gotham-Medium;
    font-size:12px;
    margin:0 5px -10px 15px; 
    width:30px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
div.day-number:hover {
background:#BBA324;
}
/* shared */
td.calendar-day, td.calendar-day-np { 
    width:30px; 
    padding:5px; 
    border:0;
}
.monthName {
font-family:Gotham-Medium;
color:#BBA324;
font-size:16px;
margin-top:-5px;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
#usTitle {
font-family:Gotham-Light;
font-size:12vw;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-align:center;
}
.plusMonth {
    font-family:Gotham-Medium;
    color:#000;
    font-size: 10px;
    float:right;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.prevMonth {
    font-family:Gotham-Medium;
    color:#000;
    font-size: 10px;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.arrow {
    font-family:Gotham-Light;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#cal2,#cal3{
    display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: What do you get in the final rendered page ? may be php is issuing some warnings ??

Comment: The only warnings I get in error reporting are the usual "Do not rely on the time settings of the server..."

Comment: Well then check the `HTML` source of the rendered page if you are breaking any tags on the rendered calander..

Comment: This works: http://deehutton2.xerohost.co/visit-us/test.php. However, if I add the PHP in the second DIV in the exact same manner as the first, the jQuery fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `calander.css` remove the following code

```
#cal2, #cal3 {
 display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you include the `calendar.php` script into the script that wants to use it.

Its a function so it only runs when called.

Remove the unnecessary `html` from the `calendar.php` script and also the code at the bottom setting the month and year variables. This would need to be done just prior to calling the `draw_calendar()` function so you can create 3 divs for current, -1 and -2 months ( I assume thats what you will be doing ).

**index.php**

```
<?php
    // make the function available in this script
    include( 'calendar.php');
?>
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style2.css" />
  <!-- make the css available in this page -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calendar.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>

  <button id="prev" disabled="disabled">Prev</button>
  <button id="next">Next</button>

    <div id="cal1" class="first current">
<?php 
    // set a value for $nmonth / $cmonth / $cyear
    // I assume this will be current month
    // TODO: Set correct month and year value
    $cmonth = date('m');
    $nmonth = date('F');
    $cyear = date('Y');

    echo '<span class="monthName">'.$nmonth.' '.$cyear.'</span>';
    echo draw_calendar($cmonth,$cyear); 
?>
        <span class="prevMonth"></span>
    </div>

    <div id="cal2">
<?php 
    // set a value for $nmonth / $cmonth / $cyear
    // I assume this will be current month -1
    // TODO: Set correct month and year value
    $cmonth = date('m');
    $nmonth = date('F');
    $cyear = date('Y');

     echo '<span class="monthName">'.$nmonth.' '.$cyear.'</span>';
     echo draw_calendar($cmonth,$cyear); 
?>
        <span class="prevMonth"></span>
    </div>

    <div id="cal3" class="last">
<?php 
    // set a value for $nmonth / $cmonth / $cyear
    // I assume this will be current month -2
    // TODO: Set correct month and year value
    $cmonth = date('m');
    $nmonth = date('F');
    $cyear = date('Y');

    echo '<span class="monthName">'.$nmonth.' '.$cyear.'</span>';
    echo draw_calendar($cmonth,$cyear); 
?>
        <span class="prevMonth"></span>
    </div>

</body>
<script>
  $('#next').click(function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
        .next().show().addClass('current');
    if ($('.current').hasClass('last')) {
        $('#next').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    $('#prev').attr('disabled', null);
});

$('#prev').click(function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
        .prev().show().addClass('current');
    if ($('.current').hasClass('first')) {
        $('#prev').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    $('#next').attr('disabled', null);
});
</script>
</html>
```

**calendar.php**
Remove all the unnecessary html at the beginning of the file i.e. this stuff:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calendar.css" />
</head>
</html>
```

also remove this from the end of the file:

```
$cmonth = date('m');
$nmonth = date('F');
$cyear = date('Y');
```